# What is .gnupg directory in the home directory?

Tags: home

I found a strange directory in my home directory on Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon (though I'm pretty confident it's on all Linux distros) called .gnupg. It has no access given to ANYONE other than root. So I have three questions:

1. What is this directory? What does it contain?
2. Why is it placed in the user's home directory yet doesn't give them any access?
3. Will it do any harm by just entering the directory as root?

Comment: did you ever run `gpg` (or `mutt` or something else which might have run `gpg`) while `su`-ed to root?

Comment: I may have when copying commands off instructions but why?

Comment: @Rohan that would give root permission of that file if in a certain context

Comment: So I made it owned by root by running the command?

Comment: yep.  when root creates a file or dir, it's owned by root.

Comment: Will that prove to be an issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most dot files have a name that resembles the application that uses it. Unsurprisingly, `.gnupg` is used by [GnuPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard). GnuPG (also known as GPG) is a program that encrypts and signs files. As soon as you invoke it for the first time, it will create a `.gnupg` directory in your home directory and a few files in it. This directory contains a lot of private information (e.g. who your contacts are), so it's accessible only to the owner. This could happen, for example, if someone sends you a signed email; if your email client supports PGP email then it will attempt to verify the signature (and fail since you don't have the sender's public key in your GPG keyring).

The real question here is why this directory in your home directory is owned by root. The answer is that you ran GPG as root, but with `HOME` set to your own home directory. Or, more precisely, you ran a program which ran GPG under the hood. One such program is APT: package management tools (`apt-get`, `apt`, `aptitude`, etc.) use GPG to verify that the packages that you download are genuine. If you ran something like `sudo apt-get install SOMEPACKAGE`, this would create a `.gnupg` directory in your home directory, since `sudo` doesn't change the home directory by default.

The fix is to remove the `.gnupg` directory, then create it under your user. You can just remove the root-owned directory (`sudo rm -r ~/.gnupg`): any file under your home directory is fair game for you. You could alternatively move it to root's home directory (`sudo mv ~/.gnupg /root`), but it doesn't contain anything important anyway. Then run a GPG command such as `gpg --list-keys`; this will populate your `~/.gnupg` directory with empty keyring files.

Just entering a directory is always harmless. Listing files and viewing their content is usually harmless, but [it can be harmful in some configurations because terminals parse escape sequences in what applications print](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56307/can-cat-ing-a-file-be-a-potential-security-risk/56323#56323). Under Linux, plain `ls` or `ls -l` is fine but `ls -N` is potentially risky. Plain `cat filename` is risky but `less filename` is fine (whereas `less +R filename` is risky). In the `.gnupg` directory, there's nothing harmful.

Comment: Is it important for me to make it owned by me again? I am likely going to run `sudo apt-get ...` MANY times in the future, so it may be a vain task. Also, thank you for the explanation, though I am still a Linux noob, so I didn't get a lot of it :(.

Comment: @Rohan If `~/.gnupg` already exists, running GPG as root will still work fine. I think it won't touch it at all in this case, the only problem is that `gpg` creates `~/.gnupg` if it doesn't already exists, and then the owner is the user that ran `gpg`, not the user whose home directory the directory is under.

Comment: so should I still make it owned by me, or will it just get changed back after `sudo apt-get ...`?

Comment: @Rohan Yes, make it owned by you (or rather: delete the one created by root, then create one owned by you). It won't get changed back.

Comment: Thank you, worked like a charm! But just out of curiosity, what might happen if I left it owned by root?

Comment: @Rohan If you leave it owned by root, you won't be able to use gpg the day you want it. And even if you never use it, you might get weird errors from a mail client that automatically tries to verify PGP signatures.

Answer (score 3):

The directory `~/.gnupg` is where configuration files for GnuPG, the GNU Privacy Guard, reside. This is a common cryptography tool (see https://www.gnupg.org/).

Its permissions should give you access, and perhaps nobody else. If the directory is owned by root on your system, that is strange. Is it really? Check by running `ls -ld ~/.gnupg`.

This directory by itself causes no harm, and it's OK for you to look at what is inside.

Comment: I've checked everything. `ls -ld ~/.gnupg` returns `drwx------ root root' as the permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add that you can change the location of this folder using the `GNUPGHOME` environment variable.

```
export GNUPGHOME="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}/gnupg"
```

See [`homedir`](https://www.gnupg.org/gph/en/manual/r1616.html) and [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GnuPG#Configuration)